# Play Framework 2 content negotiation

Tags: playframework

Just starting out with Play Framework (v2.4), and trying to understand content negotiation.  I come from an ASP.NET MVC/Web API background.  In Web API we get somewhat automated content negotiation (at least in terms of Xml and JSON).  It seems with Play that people are encouraged to test request headers in each action method to determine the appropriate content type and then calling Json.toJson() etc.

Is there some way to configure the application such that this boilerplate code is not needed?

Comment: It shouldn't be boilerplate code in almost any situation. But no, there is no way to configure such a thing.

Comment: @gpgekko A feature to return XML vs JSON based on content type headers should be trivial to implement at the framework level.  Having to implement that on each controller action is "boilerplate" code IMO.

Comment: If you do the exact same thing for each controller action, you can create a function that does it for you...